# date('Z') for a specific date (not for now)

Tags: php

> date('Z') - Timezone offset in seconds. The offset for timezones west of UTC is always negative, and for those east of UTC is always positive.

So this is an offset for now (this moment of time).

Is there any way to get the offset in seconds for a specific time (for ex: 2012-02-17 12:00).

I am aware I can achieve this using DateTime class.
But is it possible to achieve this using date() only?

Edit:

If server is in Toronto and it's summer => date('Z') => -14400

If server is in Toronto and it's winter => date('Z') => -18000

Comment: date() only no, its for formatting, your just subtracting one date from another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) with the date:

```
$getDate = '2012-02-17 12:00';
date('Z',strtotime($getDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because your datetime string doesn't contain any TZ information. If you call `date('Z')`, it's going to use the TZ set by `date_default_timezone_set()` or the .ini `date.timezone` default.

To put it in perspective, if you've got a time string saying "It's 3am", you have no idea WHERE in the world that 3am is right now. If I'm telling it to you, it'd be GMT-6 because I'm in CST, but in Saskatchewan, which doesn't observe Daylight Savings at all, so my CST is different from everyone else's CST.

But you don't know I'm in Saskatchwean. It if I said it's 3am, but I'm actually in Japan, then that's a whole different timezone, but you have absolutely NO way of telling which timezone I'm in merely by being given "3am".

At best you could compare the server's local time with the given timestring and figure out an offset from that. e.g. I say it's 3am, you know it's 5am, so obviously I'm in a place that's 2 hours behind you.

Comment: The OP wanted to get the offset based on the server's timezone, so as long as he knows where the server is, he should be okay.

Comment: yes, he modded the question to say that. when I posted this, his edits weren't up yet.